# Removing characters from lists in pandas column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, replace

I have a pandas DataFrame `df` with two columns (`NACE` and `cleaned`) which looks like this:

```
    NACE     cleaned
0   071 [260111, 260112]
1   072 [2603, 2604, 2606, 261610, 261690, 2607, 2608]
2   081 [251511, 251512, 251520, 251611, 251612, 25162]
3   089 [251010, 251020, 2502, 25030010, 251110, 25112]
4   101 [020110, 02012020, 02012030a), 02012050, 020130]
... ... ...
92  324 [95030021, 95030041, 95030049, 95030029, 95030]
93  325 [901841, 90184910, 90184990b), 841920, 90183110]
94  329 [960310, 96039010, 96039091, 96039099, 960321]
95  331 [-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-, 983843]
96  332 [-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-]
```

The `cleaned` column consists of lists of strings, some of which still contain characters that need to be removed. Specifically I need to remove all `+`, `-`, and `)`.

To focus on one of these `+`, I have tried many methods including:

```
df['cleaned'] = df['cleaned'].str.replace('+', '')
```

but also:

```
df.replace('+', '', regex = True, inplace = True)
```

and a desperate:

```
for i in df['cleaned']:
    for x in i:
        i.replace('+', '')
```

Different versions of these solutions work on most dataframes, but not when the column consists of lists.

Answer (score 0):

Just change

```
for i in df['cleaned']:
  for x in i:
    i.replace('+', '')
```

to:

```
for i in df['cleaned']:
  for x in range(len(i)):
    i[x].replace('+', '')
```

it should work.